# PHPUnit - Selenium 2: How to select an iframe without id and name?

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select an iframe with PHPUnit Selenium, but somehow it seems not to work. This is the code:

```
<body>
...
<div id="container">
<iframe src="x.html">
    <html>
    ...
    <body></body> <!-- this is the body I would like to get -->
    ...
    </html>
</iframe>
</div>
...
</body>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
class Test extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {

    public function testIframe() {

        $theFrame = $this->byCssSelector('#container iframe');

        $this->frame($theFrame->getId());

        $this->byCssSelector('body')->text('test');

    }
}
```

If I check the $theFrame variable, it is an PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element with id=5, but somehow the $this->frame($theFrame->getId()) throws an error:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Unable to locate frame: 5
Command duration or timeout: 32 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:52:59'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-39-generic',         
java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Session ID: 0192c3aa-d4a2-4c9d-bcca-bbd7139dd8c3
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,     
javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox,     
browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, 
rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true,     
takesScreenshot=true, version=20.0}]
```

Do you have any idea of why?

Answer (score 2):

Give some id or name to iframe and use the below code, it will work.

```
$this->frame('id/name');
$this->byCssSelector('body')->text('test');
```

If there are multiple iframes, then assign the value null and start fetching the according to hierarchy(parent->child->so on)

```
$this->frame(null);
$this->frame('parentFrame');
$this->frame('childFrame');
```

Answer (score 0):

having the same issue, and my workaround is to execute a javascript that will iterate all iframe tags, then determine the iframe you want to target by its existing attribute, and then set your own attribute as unique identifier.

```
 $this->execute(array(
        'script' => "
            var myiFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            for(var i=0; i<=myiFrames.length; i++)
            {
                //determine iframe by src which may contain 'test' str
                if( myiFrames[i].getAttribute('src').search('test')>=0 ){
                    myiFrames[i].setAttribute('myCustomId', 'myTargetFrame')
                }
            }",
        'args' => array()
    ));
```

then you can now target your iframe by xpath...

```
$myframe = $this->byXPath("//*[@myCustomId='myTargetFrame']");
$this->frame($frame->attribute('id'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below method to switch to a frame using it's index. To switch to a first frame present in a webpage we can use the below method.

```
 public function switchToIFrame($index = 0) {

                           $this->session->getDriver()->switchToIFrame($index);

                                              }
```

Comment: I get an error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getDriver() on a non-object - seems like session isn't present

Comment: I am not into PHP. basically i'm from Java background. In Java there is a function named `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` Hopefully there should be an equivalent method in PHP. I got the above solution from Google.

Comment: ok, I'm guessing that the equivalent function would be $this->frame($index) but that doesn't work either. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: If you are using seleniumPHP bindings, you can open the bindings file and check for the exact function name.